# Can any one give example of dependency injection with MVC swift IOS?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, mvvm, dependency-injection

i bit of stuck with dependency injection with mvc swift. i have an idea of whats mvc. i just need to know how to use dependency injection? And why are we using it? what is dependency injection?
And also i need to know what is a good design pattern for IOS(swift) project? mvc or mvvm? if you guys can give answers for these questions with example(**I mean with code**) it will be very helpful for me.
Thanks!

**Model**

```
class Person {

    private var name: String?
    private var age: Int?

    init(name: String,age:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dependency injection to pass dependancies into your objects at runtime. This helps a great deal when unit testing as you can provide mock/stubbed objects instead and prevent your objects making network calls, or updating database records etc. It is also a good practice as your ViewControllers aren't configuring and initialising its dependancies, this is done outside of the class, keeping this logic away. Making it easier to swap dependancies later.

For example, in a ViewController you may pass in a network service:

```
private let service: NetworkService

init(service: NetworkService) {
    self.service = service
    super.init(nibName: String(describing: SomeViewController.self),
               bundle: .main)
}
```

To unit test this you just pass in a mock/stubbed object and the ViewController is none the wiser, it can still receive data, but it will be data you provide, so will be predictable and therefore more testable.

Comment: so in this case NetworkService is our model. then we create a object of that and we inject our dependency? is that correct?

Comment: NetworkService is just a class that handles network calls, but it could be anything. So when initialising the class we init the service, init the class by passing in the service already configured and ready to use

Comment: that's mean we should pass it in through property! okay Got it. Thanks btw

Comment: Yes, there are lots of resources online which will explain it better and provide more  examples on how to use it and its benefits